# Ivy can't resolve log4j from Maven Central

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, ivy, dependency-management

New to Apache Ivy, and can't get it to resolve the latest `log4j` jar from Maven Central. I'm using IvyDE to manage all of my dependencies and using all of its defaults, which I believe configure it to use either the Maven repo or Ibiblio.

[This link](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Clog4j%7Clog4j%7C1.2.16%7Cbundle) takes you to Maven's log4j page. From here I am just using the Apache Ivy `<dependency>` tag provided on that page:

```
<dependency org="log4j" name="log4j" rev="1.2.16" >
    <artifact name="log4j" type="bundle" />
</dependency>
```

When I add this to my `ivy.xml` file and save it inside Eclipse, IvyDE automatically runs an Ivy resolve...and I am getting an error:

> Ivy resolve job of ivy.xml in 'myProject' has encountered a problem.
>
> Impossible to resolve dependencies of myOrg#myProject;working@myMachine
>
> download failed: log4j#log4j;1.2.16!log4j.bundle
>
> download failed: log4j#log4j;1.2.16!log4j.bundle
>
> download failed: log4j#log4j;1.2.16!log4j.bundle
>
> download failed: log4j#log4j;1.2.16!log4j.bundle

(Those last 4 lines, although identical, *are in fact repeated* 4 times!)

Is something wrong with log4j on Maven Central?  **All of my other jars resolve without a hitch**, and I am using the same technique for getting all of my jars. This is the only one (out of 30 or so) that is failing. Thanks in advance!

Comment: what ivy version do you have? this question popped up today: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9738075/ivy-why-is-trying-to-download-yyyy-bundle-and-can-i-avoid-that#comment12388050_9738075 . Maybe it is the same problem for you, too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Leave out the

```
<artifact name="log4j" type="bundle" />
```

part and it will download the normal jar file.

I don't think you need the bundle-specification part and it seems (to me) like some kind of anomaly.

`bundle` is not even a [core packaging value](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Maven_Coordinates) for maven:

> The current core packaging values are: pom, jar, maven-plugin, ejb,
>   war, ear, rar, par. These define the default list of goals which
>   execute to each corresponding build lifecycle stage for a particular
>   package structure.

Comment: I had exactly the same issue WITHOUT the artifact and type parts. Just: <dependency org="log4j" name="log4j" rev="1.2.17"/> and Ivy failed to fetch it. All other dependencies (e.g. slf4j-api, slf4j-log4j12) were fetched without a hitch. In the end I had to download the jar myself and add it in the runtime classpath.

Answer (score 2):

I used following :

```
<dependency org="log4j" name="log4j" rev="1.2.17">
            <artifact name="log4j" type="jar" />
        </dependency>
```

and it worked.

Comment: this has worked for me as well whereas the accepted answer failed in my case.

Comment: well..this is alternate solution I guess. too bad you can't accept 2 answers