# ivy - why is trying to download yyyy.bundle and can I avoid that?

Tags: ivy

We recently transformed a maven pom to ivy but are getting this error for many things(not all things):

```
[NOT FOUND  ] org.apache.geronimo.specs#geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec;1.7.1!geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec.bundle (11649ms)
```

The only difference between the pom files that work and don't is there a package element with the value "bundle".

Maven is working fine.  How can we get ivy working as it gets the pom and just really needed to download the jar artifact.

More info, I changed my ivysettings so it ends in .jar instead of [ext] like so

This workardoun worked but I am worried now source downloads won't work anymore.  Unfortunately, I don't control the poms in the repository that specify bundle in the packaging attribute.  Is there a way to override certain things in ivy so I can fix all these and not use my temporary workaround?

I copied from the pom in nexus for that url which is the following and notice packaging is bundle

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
     <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.genesis</groupId>
     <artifactId>genesis-java5-flava</artifactId>
     <version>2.0</version>
  </parent>
  <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
  <artifactId>geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec</artifactId>
  <packaging>bundle</packaging>
  <name>JavaMail 1.4</name>
  <version>1.7.1</version>
  <description>Javamail 1.4 Specification</description>
  <url>
     http://geronimo.apache.org/maven/${siteId}/${version}
  </url>
  <distributionManagement>
     <site>
       <id>apache-website</id>
       <url>${site.deploy.url}/maven/${siteId}/${version}</url>
     </site>
  </distributionManagement>
```

The pom that brings that in is cxf-bundle which I depend on.  The dependency in the cxf-bundle is

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
   <artifactId>geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec</artifactId>
   <version>1.7.1</version>
   <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

thanks,
Dean

Comment: can you add the dependency configuration for that artifact please

Comment: maybe this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9737262/ivy-cant-resolve-log4j-from-maven-central/9737593#9737593) that arised a few moments ago, may help too. If you have type="bundle" somehwere,  it is worth a look.

Comment: hmmm, how to add the configuration as this dependency is transitive and I am not sure what sucks it in at this point.

Comment: what I find strange is, that a similar question popped up today. Perhaps they broke the repo ... any chance you could contact them and ask them why they set packaging to bundle? If you look at the other question this seems anormal (to me)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Darnit, I copied the example on the ivy site which downloads an older version that has this bug

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IVY-899

The newest version works just fine.

Comment: +1 I wasn't aware that ivy had special handling for OSGi bundles